# How to tighten spark plugs properly?

Tags: sparkplugs

Hyundai coupe 2.0 2006

1. I cannot see it in the owners manual.  Can anyone tell me what the torque setting for spark plugs on this vehicle are?
2. How can I do this properly without a torque wrench.  I’ve seen some videos where they tighten it by hand and when it doesn’t turn further then give a little nudge.  Other videos tighten by hand until it doesn’t go further then go another half turn or 2/3rds of a turn.  This would be very different final torques I imagine.   In both cases I can’t tell just how much force they applied with their hands to begin with.

So how can I do this properly without a torque wrench?  Also does the whole process allow for some variation so if you are over or under certain amount of pounds it won’t matter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Old-style plug spanners were cheap and wimpy tools that looked like this:

[image: T-style spark plug wrench]

https://www.halfords.com/tools/hand-tools/all-hand-tools/laser-spark-plug-spanner-t-bar-16mm-686737.html

The amount of torque you could apply to that little T-bar with one hand was about right. No torque wrench required!

Answer (score 1):

If torque specs from the engine manufacturer are unavailable I'd use the specs from the plug manufacturers.

Doing this without torque wrench is complicated and prone to errors (removing the head and repairing the plug-hole thread is expensive, more than a golden German-made torque wrench with engraved blessings from the CEO).

One screws the plug in finger-tight, then he tightens it for a certain angle. In theory the sufficient end-torque or angle depends on many things: The diameter of the plug, the form (straight or conical), the head material (aluminum or steel) and the state of the plug (used or new, as there is a crush washer that gets, ahem, crushed on the first install).

In practice the <del>obstinate</del> old-timers, after some costly mistakes, feel it quite well when enough is enough and nobody of them reads the torque (or angle) data from the specs anyway.

The whole process needs a bit of experience to do it with an acceptable success rate. I doubt that just explaining it in theory is viable.

Comment: With a bit of experience one « feels » the washer compressing but with plugs that have a conical seal surface then that is different.

Comment: See this chart>>>>http://www.ngk-sparkplugs.jp/english/techinfo/qa/q18/index.html

Comment: Or this>>>>https://www.championautoparts.com/Technical/Tech-Tips/Spark-Plug-Torque-Recommendations.html

Answer (score 0):

Most mechanics tighten by feel. But you must know the right feel. So you need a reference. Call your dealer and find the proper torque settings and use a torque wrench. Tighten the plugs and use that as a reference on how tight to turn. Remember that the torque wrench handle will probably be longer than your ratchet. You might even try torquing then down a little light with the torque wrench then tighten just a little more with your ratcet. Soon you will be able to tell how much to tighten without the torque wrench.